# Which one is a tail event?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have to check if the following 4 events are tail events or not.
$X_j \in [0,1]$ are independent random variables, we define $\tau = \bigcap_n \tau_n$ where $\tau_n = \sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\dots)$, so $\tau$ is the tail-sigma-algebra. I'll write $X_j$ instead of $X_j(\omega)$
\begin{align*}
a) & \sum_1^\infty X_j< \infty\\
b) & \sum_1^\infty X_j^2 > 2\\
c) & \prod_1^\infty X_j > 2\\
d) & \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n X_k < \infty
\end{align*}
a) $\left\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j < \infty \right\} = \left\{\sum_{j=k}^\infty X_j + \sum_{i=1}^k X_i< \infty \right\}$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i <C$ for some $C>0$ the rhs is true/false if and only if the first sum is finite/infinite, right? So we fix $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and get $\left\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j < \infty \right\} = \left\{\sum_{j=k}^\infty X_j < \infty \right\} \in \sigma(X_{i},i\ge k)$ which completes the proof because it's independent of the first k random variables and the event is a tail event. Am I right?

b) I would say the event isn't a tail event. There might be an $\omega$ s.t. $\sum_{j=1}^k X_j^2 > 2$ for a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{j=k}^\infty X_j^2 = 0 $. Is this correct? Can I assume, that such an $\omega$ exists?

c) This event can obviously never be true since $X_j \in [0,1]$. So it depends on nothing and is therefore a tail event? I really don't know.

d) I would argue as in a) and maybe define $\tilde{X}_n = \prod_{k=1}^n X_k$, then $\tilde{X}_n \in [0,1]$ and we have the same as in a)

I would appreciate if someone can check if my answers or ideas are correct.

Comment: C is the empty set, so is in the tail, yes? I agree with your a and d. I don't think you can assume what you have in b though.

Comment: How about in b considering the minimal k such that the sum of the first k X_i is larger than 2 and then go from there?

Comment: For (b), it's better to *set* the tail to be zero, so that the series become a finite sum which doesn't lie on the tail sigma-algebra.

Comment: For b, the series could diverge though, yes? Could we take an infinite series $\sum a_n= 2 $ and ask if $X_n>a_n$ infinitely often, at least for some suitably rearranged subsequence of $X_n$? Seems like that might be in the tail algebra.

Comment: @jdods No.  First, the range of $X_i$ iid is $[0,1]$.  It may be possible that (b) holds for *some* $X_i$, but in general, (b) is false.  You may want to see the application of [Kolmogorov's 0-1 law](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_du_z%C3%A9ro-un_de_Kolmogorov#Exemples) in French version of Wiki page.  $$$$ "Au contraire, l’événement $$\left\lbrace\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} X_{k}>1\right\rbrace$$ **n'est pas un événement queue** dans le cas général (par exemple en supposant ces variables aléatoires positives), puisqu’il **n’est pas indépendant de la valeur de $X_{1}$**."

Comment: @GNUSupporter, But couldn't the distribution of the $X_i$ be so heavily weighted towards $1$, e.g. deterministically $1$, such that the series diverge a.a.? Is it that, in general it isn't a tail event, but it could be for some cases? So doesnt the answer depend on the distribution in question?

Comment: @jdods An **assertion** "object $\star$ has property $(P)$" is wrong is we can find a counterexample.  Provided the existence of a counterexample, the assertion is wrong no matter examples exist or not.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, Sure, I'm not arguing against that. I was just wondering if it is correct that it could be in the tail for some cases. Would those cases only be "trivial" though?

Comment: @jdods I see.  If they're deterministically constant, then the event become either $\varnothing$ or $\Omega$, and we don't need to do probability.  But I don't think so even though we have $X_i$ concentrated on $1$, since we can't get rid of $\{X_1 ??? \}$ from the sum.

Comment: I tried to understand or translate the French version of the Kolmogorov page, but I don't get it. And I don't understand why my idea is not possible. Since the $X_j$ are in [0,1], there is a (maybe infinitesimal) probability, that $X_j$ becomes arbitrary small, like $X_j(\omega)< c*j^{-2}$ for a $c>0$. So why can't we say, that such an $\omega$ exists in the $\sigma$- algebra?

Comment: @GNUSupporter, If $X_i$ density is zero on $[0,a]$ for some $a\in(0,1)$, then $\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k^2>2\}=\Omega\in\tau$ (which I suppose is a trivial case). Of course we do seemingly lose info about $X_1$ etc. but it doesn't matter since we are just looking at a subset of $\Omega$. I argue that the question is ill-formed if the answer depends on other information not given. Of course, I may be missing something important.

Comment: @ChristianManthey, see my comment. Maybe the $X_i$ are never close to zero (pdf is zero nearby). Is this question from a textbook? If so, which one? Or maybe from you instructors notes? You might ask for clarification from them.

Comment: @jdods the questions are from my professor. She was in a hurry and randomly wrote down some events. And she added the power 2 afterwards, which is very confusing since it shouldn't change anything. I see now what you mean, I'll ask her to make things clear